# Error, Return value 3221225477 on running c code runtime error

Tags: c, struct, return, runtime-error

I was trying to write a program that would have an array of employees and by reading from the input do some things such as adding another new employee, deleting one, showing the list of all employees or exit the program but as I dealt with all the errors in my code and was able to finally compile it, I had this return value and I don't know what to do with it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
struct employee{
     int id;
    char* name;
};
int main(){
    char* input;
    employee person[30];
    int employee_count=0;
    bool command=false;
    while(input !="exit"){
        fgets(input, 100, stdin); 
        char* temp;
        strncpy(input, temp, 3);
        if(temp=="add"){
            char* name;
            for(int x=0; x<100; x+=1){
                temp[x]='\0';
            }
            int i=4;
            for(; input[i]!=' '; i+=1){ 
                const char* tmp = &input[i];
                temp=strcat((char*)temp,tmp);
            }
            person[employee_count+1].name=temp;
            name=temp;
            for(int x=0; x<100; x+=1){
                temp[x]='\0';
            }
            for(; i<strlen(input); i+=1){
                const char* tmp = &input[i];
                temp=strcat((char*)temp,tmp);
            }
            printf("%s added.", name);
            command=true;
            employee_count+=1;
        }
        strncpy(input, temp, 3);
        if(temp=="del"){
            for(int x=0; x<100; x+=1){
                temp[x]='\0';
            }
            for(int i=4; input[i]!=' '; i+=1){
                const char* tmp = &input[i];
                temp=strcat((char*)temp,tmp);
            }
            int i=0, found=0;
            for(; i<employee_count; i+=1){
                if(person[i].id==*((int*)(&temp))){
                    found=1;
                    break;
                }
                temp=person[i].name;
                if(found==1){
                    for(int j=i; j<employee_count; j+=1){
                        person[j]=person[j+1];
                    }
                    printf("%s deleted.", temp);
                }
                else{
                    printf("not found.");
                }
            }
            command=true;
            employee_count-=1;
        }
        strncpy(input, temp, 4);
        if(temp=="list"){
            for(int i=0; i<employee_count; i+=1){
                printf("%d %s", person[i].id, person[i].name);
            }
            command=true;

        }
        else if(command==false){
            printf("invalid command.\n");
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &input);` should be `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", input);` (you are passing the *location* of the pointer) **and** no memory was allocated to `input` anyway.

Comment: Note  3,221,225,477‬ --> 0xC000 0005‬.

Comment: hosseinxj0152, who suggested using `scanf("%[^\n]%*c"...`?  Research `fgets()` as a good alternative.

Comment: Moreover, you cannot compare a string with `input !="exit"` in C, which is what the code mostly look like although headed up as C++. You must use `strcmp`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I replaced my scanf with yours but I got the same result

Comment: Have you allocated any memory yet for `char* input;`? The compiler should be warning you that you are using an uninitialised varaible.

Comment: Here `char* temp;` is another uninitialsed pointer which you are comparing and reading into in a similar bad way. You can't just define a pointer and start indexing it. I think you need to examine your whole code, line by line, telling yourself what each does, and if it is allowed to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and to C programming.  Look carefully at what @chux-ReinstateMonica wrote.  Then Google that error.  Note how that tells you exactly what kind of error -- and other comments have told you at least two places where you are causing that error.  This should be enough info to find the problem.  Using pointers in C is confusing when you are not used to it.  You have to have them point to something before you can do anything with them.

Comment: Why don't Windows IDEs decode NTSTATUS exit codes to human-meaningful error messages?  We get so many questions just about this one that I recognize the number on sight, but people shouldn't have to memorize the numbers. Even "STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION" would be better than this.